# How can I get random numbers from the range attribute between minimum value and the current value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The minimum is 20 the maximum is 300.
If in the inspector for example the current value of the slider is 120 then pick a random number between 20 and 120 and if before running the game or while the game is running I'm changing the value to 77 then the next random number should be between 20 and 77.

I want that each X random seconds each time that the npcs will do something.
For example after running the game if the random number is 20 or 90 then after 20 seconds or 90 seconds the npcs will do something. Then the next random number if it's 199 then after 199 seconds the npcs will do the same thing(something) and so on.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> npcs;
    [Range(20, 300)]
    public int timeVisit = 20;
    public string nextVisitTime;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        npcs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Npc").ToList();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: [Unity Random.Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html), [C# Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 0):

To generate X radom numbers between 20 and 300 and add them to a list:

```
Random r = new Random();
List<int> rands = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    rands.Add(r.Next(20, 300));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't explain it good.

This is what I wanted and is working. I'm taking the random number from between the minimum and current values of the slider of the range attribute the slider in the inspector.

Then later I will make that each time I'm changing the value in the inspector and it's picking up a random number it will start a coroutine that will wait the random picked seconds when it finish the npcs will do something.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> npcs;
    [Range(20, 300)]
    public int timeVisit = 20;
    public string nextVisitTime;

    private int oldtimevisit;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        npcs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Npc").ToList();

        oldtimevisit = timeVisit;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(timeVisit != oldtimevisit)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            Debug.Log(Random.Range(20,timeVisit));

            var timetowait = Random.Range(20, timeVisit);
            StartCoroutine(Waiting(timetowait));
        }

        oldtimevisit = timeVisit;
    }

    IEnumerator Waiting(int waitingtime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitingtime);

        DoSomethingWithNpcs();
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithNpcs()
    {

    }
}
```